# How to start/stop service with Apache2 on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, service, setuid

Using Apache, I'd like to be able to start and stop a service on the same server. Essentially, I'm looking for a way to allow Apache (or some script called by Apache) to call `sudo service XXXX start`.

I realize there are severe security implications with this, and I'm looking to minimize the possible effects. There is only a single service that I need to do this for. I've seen some solutions that involve "hacking" the `setuid` (C/Perl wrapper), others involved editing the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Is there a better way?

many thanks,
S.

Comment: On the apache side, you want to protect this using digest authentication AND SSL. If at all possible, use a client certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest letting the www-data-user use that one init.d-script as sudo without password by adding this to your /etc/sudoers

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/theinitscript
```

And then use `sudo /etc/init.d/theinitscript start` instead of the command service.

Comment: That did it. I changed "apache" to "www-data". THANKS!